Issue with finding optimal MTU size using PowerShell script in Win 11
I tried the ping command to get the MTU size using PowerShell script but it does not give me accurate reading as it show it can not find optimal size within given range. However, manually putting it works just fine. Can you help me with what I am doing wrong here?
cat .\FindOptimalMTU.ps1
param (
    [string]$destination
)

if (-not $destination) {
    Write-Host "Usage: .\FindOptimalMTU.ps1 <destination>"
    exit 1
}

# Define the starting MTU size
$startMTU = 1300

# Function to perform ping test for a specific MTU size
function Test-MTU {
    param (
        [int]$mtu
    )
    $pingSize = $mtu
    $pingCommand = "ping"
    $pingArguments = "-f -l $pingSize -n 1 $destination"

    # Run the ping command and capture the output
    $pingResult = & $pingCommand $pingArguments 2>&1 | Out-String

    # Check if the output contains the fragmentation message
    if ($pingResult -match "Packet needs to be fragmented" -or $pingResult -match "Request timed out") {
        return $false
    } else {
        return $true
    }
}

# Iterate over the MTU sizes starting from $startMTU
$maxMTU = 10000
$optimizedMTU = 0
for ($mtu = $startMTU; $mtu -le $maxMTU; $mtu++) {
    if (-not (Test-MTU -mtu $mtu)) {
        $optimizedMTU = $mtu - 1
        break
    }
}

if ($optimizedMTU -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No suitable MTU size found"
} else {
    $finalMTU = $optimizedMTU + 28
    Write-Host "Optimal MTU size: $optimizedMTU (Effective MTU including headers: $finalMTU)"
}

Expected result should be 1480 after adding 28 for icmp header and other value addition to 1452 which can be explicitly shown by manually obtaining it by writing this
ping -f -l 1452 -n 4 9.9.9.11

Pinging 9.9.9.11 with 1452 bytes of data:
Reply from 9.9.9.11: bytes=1452 time=4ms TTL=59
Reply from 9.9.9.11: bytes=1452 time=4ms TTL=59
Reply from 9.9.9.11: bytes=1452 time=5ms TTL=59
Reply from 9.9.9.11: bytes=1452 time=5ms TTL=59

Ping statistics for 9.9.9.11:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 4ms, Maximum = 5ms, Average = 4ms

ping -f -l 1453 -n 4 9.9.9.11

Pinging 9.9.9.11 with 1453 bytes of data:
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.

Ping statistics for 9.9.9.11:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

But the above FindOptimalMTU.ps1 shows this
.\FindOptimalMTU.ps1 9.9.9.11
No suitable MTU size found


@John my optimal value is for PPOE connection...
